# jQuery .ajax() calls failing

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to make a jQuery `.ajax()` call to a public web service, and I'm having trouble finding the right syntax.

I've tried several different implementations. This one:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.jsonp',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function() {
    alert('JSONP call succeeded!');
  }
});
```

It fails with the following error:

```
all.jsonp:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined
```

And this one:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json',
  dataType: "json",
  success: function() {
    alert('JSON call succeeded!');
  }
});
```

Fails with this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json. Origin http://localhost:8888 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I'm serving the page through my local IIS7 instance. I've also tried various combinations of `$.getJSON()` with similar results. What am I missing?

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joshearl/gya3b/) of the above code.

UPDATE: Thought we had a solution, but I'm still getting the `callback is not defined` error when doing the JSONP calls, even though the alert/log code gets called. The response URL looks like this:

```
http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.jsonp?callback=undefined&157148585
```

and the JSON response is wrapped like this:

```
callback({"StatusMsg": "OK", "Results": {"BD": {"Name": "Bangladesh", "Capital": {"DLST": "null", "TD": 6.0, "Flg": 2, "Name": "Dhaka", ...
```

I've found examples with the callback name added on to the end of the URL in the `.ajax()` configuration, but when I try that I get the same result, only it's tacked on to the end of my query string.

Comment: Don't use `alert()` to debug. Use `console.log()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This regular JSON call will not work because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This is what your error is telling you with: `is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

**The correct JSONP syntax is:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.jsonp',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/gya3b/5/)

Comment: I'm aware of the same origin policy. However, JSONP is not. But I'm having trouble figuring out the correct callback syntax with jQuery.

Comment: @JoshEarl I was still adding the syntactical fixes for the JSONP piece. This will work fine.

Comment: Yep, works great. Still not sure I understand the `jsonpCallback` syntax. Is it telling the browser what to expect the wrapper function will be called? All of the examples I've found so far describe appending whatever name you want to the end of your URL. Maybe this API just doesn't support naming your own callback.

Comment: You can call it whatever you want and it should work just the same *on your end*. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/gya3b/6/). They expect you to name it `callback`, though, so you should probably stick with that convention.

Comment: If I use exactly what you have above, it works and outputs an Object to the console. If I make any changes at all, something breaks: using a different name in `jsonpCallback`, using a function name for `success` instead of an inline function. Bleh--hate copy/paste programming. The documentation on this is really poor. Appreciate the help, though.

Answer (score 2):

The correct usage is buried in the documentation for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  Search for the `jsonpCallback` option.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.jsonp',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: function() {
    alert('JSONP call succeeded!');
  }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gya3b/3/

Comment: Thanks, Matt. The `jsonpCallback` piece was what I was missing.

Comment: You'll see in my answer that you can specify the string `'callback'` which will effectively use your `success: function()`.

Comment: Or you do it my way and use one less property. :)

Comment: I haven't used jsonpCallback, but documentation sez: "jsonpCallback...  This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery... As of jQuery 1.5, you can also use a function for this setting, in which case the value of jsonpCallback is set to the return value of that function."  The way I read that this would set the callback function to the name 'true'. (So the url, observed in fiddler, would have '?callback=true' at the end). Does it?

Comment: I think standardizing all your success code to the `success` function makes sense, but maybe that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work if you create a **proxy** to load the url for you.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'proxy.php?url=http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function() {
        alert('JSON call succeeded!');
    }
});
```

Here `proxy.php` will load `http://www.geognos.com/api/en/countries/info/all.json` for you.

About the **JSONP** part, your syntax is invalid. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more.

Comment: Using JSONP will solve the problem. This answer is incorrect. Introducing a proxy is over-architecting something that has a much simpler answer.

Comment: Oops! didin't check geognos.com supports jsonp.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make a web service call to a domain that is not of the same origin (i.e base URL) you need to use a proxy to do so. proxies are not necessarily obligated to the same domain restrictions.

They are different depending on the platform you are working with, i.e .NET/LAMP.

This website has multiple posts on how to create either.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can fix this. By setting your jsoncallback.

```
$.ajax(url, { dataType: 'jsonp', jsonp: 'jsoncallback' })
    .then(function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log('success (promises): ' + data.name);
}, function(xhr, status, error) {
    console.log('failed (promises): ' + error);
});
```