# Getting an error when trying to load json data from remote location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

I have a students.json file on the remote server with this data

```
{
"studentId":101,
"firstName":"Carissa",
"lastName":"Page",
"emailId":"laoreet.libero.et@Mauris.net"
}
```

Now i am trying to read students.json from different server (cross-domain) using jQuery.ajax().

This is my html page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Metadata Test Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="studentdisplay">
    <p>Getting Student Details</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this code in my JavaScript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://rupeshreddy.com/students.json',
      contentType: "application/json",               
      dataType:"jsonp",
      success: function (data) {

           var output;
           output = '<table><tr><th colspan=2>Student</th></tr>';
           output += '<tr><td>First Name</td><td>'+ data.firstName +'</td></tr>';
           output += '<tr class="alt"><td>Last Name</td><td>'+ data.lastName +'</td></tr>';
           output += '<tr><td>Student Id</td><td>'+ data.studentId +'</td></tr></table>';

          $("#studentdisplay").html( output );         
      }
})

.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $("#studentdisplay").html(textStatus+" - "+errorThrown);

      });    
});
```

When i open the web page i getting this error:

> parsererror - Error: jQuery111006872769086621702_1395648763612 was not
>   called".

This same code works fine when both .html and .json file are on the same server (of course datatype will be then json). The error occurs only when both files are in different server.

I looked through so many past questions and articles, but non of them helped me solve this issue. Any help and suggestions are appreciated.

Link to JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/rL5fK/1/

===================================================

## Update - Solved

I wrapped my data in students.json like this callback({...data...})
now my student.json was like this

```
callback({
"studentId":101,
"firstName":"Carissa",
"lastName":"Page",
"emailId":"laoreet.libero.et@Mauris.net"
})
```

In my ajax call i added addition line jsonpCallback: 'callback'.
Now my call was like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://rupeshreddy.com/students.json',
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: 'callback',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);


        var output;
           output = '<table border="1"><tr><th colspan=2>Student</th></tr>';
           output += '<tr><td>First Name</td><td>'+ data.firstName +'</td></tr>';
           output += '<tr class="alt"><td>Last Name</td><td>'+ data.lastName +'</td></tr>';
           output += '<tr><td>Student Id</td><td>'+ data.studentId +'</td></tr></table>';

          $("#studentdisplay").html( output );
    }
});
```

Working JSFIDDLE link http://jsfiddle.net/esWSH/2/

Thanks everyone

Comment: Is your error block of ajax call getting triggered?

Comment: @Felix If i use dataType:"json" i am getting this in developer tools Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @dreamweiver Yes error block of ajax call getting triggered, and throws this "error parsererror - Error: jQuery111006872769086621702_1395648763612 was not called"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important also to look in the Network tab of your Developer Tools.

You would find this:

[image: Network]
[image: Network]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried wrapping my json data like this ({...}) and ({...}); in json file, But still got the same error. I am think i am missing some small thing, i not able to figure out what it is. Anyway thanks for suggesting Developer Tools.

Comment: You need to wrap it in whatever the callback tells you to. Something like this with PHP: `<?=$_GET['callback']?>({your json here})`

Comment: I am not using PHP to generate my JSON, i have a direct JSON file with data.

Comment: Then you need to tell jQuery what `callback` you will be using, and wrap your JSON with that callback.

Comment: I changed my student.json as you suggested, i wrapped my data like this callback({....Data ..}) added this line in ajax call "jsonpCallback: 'callback'", and it worked. part of it was based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673050/jquery-ajax-calls-failing

Comment: Add this line jsonpCallback: 'callback',

Answer (score 0):

Might be because cross-domain Ajax calls be prohibited on that URL.
Your code is working perfectly. [Have a look at the jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L6PHS/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="studentdisplay">
    <p>Getting Student Details</p>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    //post the request to /echo/json/ and specify the correct datatype
    url: '/echo/json/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
        //you get back exactly what you sent in the json 
        console.log(data);
        var output;
        output = '<table><tr><th colspan=2>Student</th></tr>';
        output += '<tr><td>First Name</td><td>' + data.firstName + '</td></tr>';
        output += '<tr class="alt"><td>Last Name</td><td>' + data.lastName + '</td></tr>';
        output += '<tr><td>Student Id</td><td>' + data.studentId + '</td></tr></table>';
        $("#studentdisplay").html(output);
    },
    type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: It seems like this example simulate same domain or same origin. My code works fine in when both files are in same domain, but want it work when they are on different servers (cross domain).

Comment: @Rup that's what I meant by `cross domain ajax request's might be blocked on that URL`. This demo was just to show you that your code's perfect.